# Sufficient condition for existence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

I'm looking for a sufficient condition on the matrices $A,B,C$ and $D$ such that there exists vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that
\begin{align}
 A y &= B x, \\
 A z &= C x + Dy, 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
 y_i &\neq 0 \text{ for each } i = 1,\ldots, m, \\
 z_i &\neq 0 \text{ for each } i = 1,\ldots, m, \\
 y_i - z_i &\neq 0 \text{ for each } i = 1,\ldots, m.
\end{align}

**Sufficient condition:** If $A$ is invertible and if no row of

$$M:=\begin{pmatrix}  A^{-1}B\\  C+DA^{-1}B\\  A^{-1}B - C-DA^{-1}B \end{pmatrix}$$

is the null vector.

I'm looking for a condition that doesn't assume invertibility.

---

Context: $A,B,C$ and $D$ describe parts of some dynamical system. Exists of such vectors $x,y$ and $z$ guarantees properties of the system.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139105/discussion-on-question-by-sum-math-sufficient-condition-for-existence-of-vectors).